Google SignIn requires additional access to your google account
I am working on iOS Swift application and using the Google SignIn. But eventually i am seeing a different description on the Google SignIn popup that says
"App Wants additional access to your google account"
Is this normal?

Here is my code
@IBAction func onGoogle(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID else { return }
    let config = GIDConfiguration(clientID: clientID)
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.configuration = config

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(withPresenting: self) { [weak self] signInResult, error in
       
        if error != nil {
            return
        }
        
        guard let signInResult = signInResult else { return }

        let user = signInResult.user
        
        let givenName = user.profile?.givenName ?? ""
        let familyName = user.profile?.familyName ?? ""
        let email = user.profile?.email ?? ""
        let token = user.accessToken.tokenString

        let socialData: [String: String] = [
            "name": givenName + " " + familyName,
            "email": email,
            "token": token,
            "login_type": LOGIN_TYPE.google.rawValue.description,
        ]
        print(socialData)
     }
}`

I tried StackoverFlow and other possible solutions for this and i am expecting what is wrong in my code.
